# Request.UrlReferrer for Response.Redirect crashes on Home Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uri

I have language switches on the website between Turkish and English. The problem was, assume the user on a page like `http://en.fastercv.com/is-ilanlari`. If he clicked the Turkish flag, he used to be redirected to home page: `http://www.fastercv.com` instead of `http://www.fastercv.com/is-ilanlari`. I sorted it out using the code below:

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer!=null)
{
     string prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     string prevUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
     Uri uri = new Uri(prevUrl);
     string prevPath = uri.PathAndQuery;
     if (uri.Host == "en.fastercv.com")
     {
          Response.Redirect("http://www.fastercv.com" + prevPath);
     }
}
```

Now the problem is, when he is on home page if he clicks the language flag, it seems going into an  endless loop. The page never loads. On Firefox it says: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.` It only happens on the home page. I suspect the `uri.Host` bit on the if check.. It's ASP.NET-MVC.

Comment: did u tried using breakpoints to debug, if yes, does your break point  enter inside the if(uri.Host == "en.fastercv.com") condition ?

Comment: I haven't. Cos, in that case "uri.host" will be "localhost". But obviously it does, as it works for pages other than Home.

Comment: ok, try to check if your uri.Host is getting is prom Host or not by writing this line inside the if(){ Response.Write(uri.Host + ", inside if");} this will show you the Host address.

Comment: Yes, the host is "en.fastercv.com"

Comment: Response.Redirect("your path", false); try this if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what causes. If the url does not have "path and query", Index() method always starts over. Rewrote the if condition:

```
if (uri.Host == "en.fastercv.com" && uri.PathAndQuery!="/")
 {
      Response.Redirect("http://www.fastercv.com" + prevPath);
 }
```